# localhost doesn't open in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, localhost

I'm having this annoying problem that when I try to open `localhost:8080` in IE9, it goes on to search the Internet for it as a keyword. It's working fine in other browsers, like Firefox and Chrome. I've also tried `http://localhost:8082/` but that too doesn't work. What is going on?

Comment: Name resolution problem? Have you tried `http://127.0.0.1:8082/`?

Comment: That too takes it as a search keyword.

Comment: Can you visit .com websites in IE9? If so, suppose you edit your hosts file, as pbaris suggests, except change localhost to localhost.com

Comment: @jmort253 Ofcourse .com websites open in IE. :)

Comment: So if you follow @pbaris's instructions, except use localhost.com and then visit http://localhost.com:8082, let us know what happens.

Comment: Maybe it's on the server side. Say, sends a `302` and `location: http://www.google.com/search?q=<hostname>`....

Comment: @infgeoax - Sounds like an April Fools joke ;)

Comment: `localhost.com:8082` also doesn't work! I'm really sick of this browser. Why doesn't it just DIE!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Apparently this problem can be caused by conflicts with IIS, if you have IIS installed. There are other issues that can cause IE9 127.0.0.1 resolutions to fail as well.

The [common steps offered by Microsoft to resolve this issue, or any issues where IE is unable to resolve a website, involve resetting the IE9 browser settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Reset-Internet-Explorer-settings-in-Internet-Explorer-9):

- Open Tools -> Internet Options
- Click on the "Advanced" tab.
- Click "Reset"
- Click the checkbox for "Delete personal settings"
- In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box, click "Reset".
- When changes are done, click "Close" and then restart the browser.

If after following these steps, the problem still hasn't disappeared, repeat the above steps, except instead of clicking "Reset" in the "Advanced" tab, click "Restore Advanced Settings", which is located below "Reset".

This [tech guide](http://www.mytechguide.org/9560/reset-internet-explorer-ries/) describes the steps for resetting the advanced settings on Windows 7 for IE9.

**NOTE:  Resetting will reset IE to factory settings. You'll lose your existing configuration and any settings or data in IE.  Judging by your love for this browser, I'm assuming there isn't any data in there that you care about. ;)  However, be sure you're okay with this before following these steps**

Comment: Thanks very much. `http://localhost:8082/` works now. But `localhost:8082` still doesn't work. Is it supposed to not work? And you are right there is nothing in there worth caring, :D

Comment: Now that is just IE9. Whenever I test things out on it, the first thing I do is type `localhost:8888` get redirected to Google, curse, then retype `http://localhost:8888` and load my page.  I guess Microsoft just doesn't put a lot of attention to detail into the  usability of their browser. I'm glad you got this figured out though :)

Comment: The page loaded after reset but then didn't work upon reloading. I just do all my IE debugging in the IE Tab Chrome extension now. It's much less of a hassle.

Comment: "Judging by your love for this browser, I'm assuming there isn't any data in there that you care about. ;)" exactly! Resetting did the trick, which is weird because I can't remember changing anything in it.

Comment: I had the same issue and didn't even need to reset, I just changed a couple settings unrelated to navigation and reloaded and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the loopback IP instead of localhost:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8082/
```

IE might be struggling to resolve localhost.

Comment: It helped me, thanks a lot! IE opened Bing instead of localhost, but using IP address http://127.0.0.1 it resolved that problem.

Answer (score 3):

go to

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\
```

and open file hosts with notepad. Is there a record like

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

if not try to add it else is IE...

Comment: If the IP address 127.0.0.1 cannot be found, then the problem is definitely not anything to do with the hosts file.

Comment: @pbaris `127.0.0.1 localhost` is there in the hosts file.

Comment: This did resolve the issue of IE hanging when testing on localhost, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If some of you still have this problem, try to open IE in private mode. It worked for me.

Comment: Amazing, this works for me too (in a situation where all other browsers can access http://localhost/whatever, but IE cannot, on a work network). Just go to the menu / Safety / InPrivate Browsing. Localhost works. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

I've already solved the problem by editing c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.
There was a line
Code: [Select]

::1 localhost

Which shouldn't be there apparently. Don't know how it got there, but removing it apparently restores localhost functionality.

This will help you to change the permission for the readonly hosts file.

[image]

Make sure that you change it back to readonly.

Comment: That line is there as a comment in my hosts file. Don't know if removing it matters.

Comment: @AliHaideri - For clarification, was it like this `# ::1 localhost` or was it only preceded by the colons?

Comment: @jmort253 It is there like you say it is, not precede by colons. Also I can't edit anything in hosts file. It says it's in use by another program.

Answer (score 1):

In Site Bindings set the IP Address to : All Unassigned / select a port (if you want).

This also works for IE 11,

[image: localhost or 127.0.0.1 does not work in IE 11]

Then Try `http://localhost:323/`

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had a VM running in background bound to the port I was trying to reach. Chrome was displaying the page correctly but IE and Firefox refused any connection to it.

I solved the problem by starting the local server on a **different port number**, i.e. 3001 instead of 3000.