# do you want to open or save from localhost while trying to upload the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to upload the file on certain path.

I have written following code for this:

```
                        try
                        {
                            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(fileLocation))
                                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(fileLocation);

                            // file.SaveAs(completefilepathWithFile);
                            file.SaveAs(FileLocationToSaveInDB);
                            return Json("File Uploaded Sucessfully");
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            return json("Failed to upload the file");
                        }
```

This code works fine for Firefox and crome.

But gives me error for IE9.

It prompts me for:

```
Do you want to openor save (methodname) from localhost?
```

Its as below:

[image]

I tried with:

[localhost doesn't open in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764008/localhost-doesnt-open-in-ie9?answertab=active#tab-top)

But didnt helped.

Please help me.

Comment: may be your ie getting wrong path

Comment: it IE behavior for downloading fie

Comment: @Justcode is there any alternative for it? how can i ditect that my IE is getting wrong path?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad but i am uploading file to server

Comment: @ÁngelDiMaría can you check in your jquery what path its getting in?

Comment: @Justcode wait , will post the path

Comment: @Justcode C:/PP_ArtifactsUploadedFiles/EvalID_941/147/1/2.txt   this is the path i get for saving the file

Comment: okay I think you should paste it into a jsfiddle for live demo

Comment: @Justcode but above code is in c#

Comment: but, I think problem is in uploading

Comment: @Justcode yes to upload the file (to save to server path) i have written above code..

Comment: Can you provide specific demo? i can't minimize your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many browsers can't handle application/json as the return content type.You can hack the response and sent back the content using the mime type text/html.

try this:

```
return Json("FileUploaded successfully", "text/html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```