# How do I set up Azure Dev Ops to build Dev Express XAF-XPO project?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package, xaf

I want to set up continuous integration and deployment for an XAP Mobile app in Azure Devops.

In order to get CI/CD I need to set up the Azure Pipeline to install the right packages.

There is some information in the docs on [Hosting your own NuGet feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview)
and [Get started with NuGet packages in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)

Dev Express explained that they do not currently provide a Nuget feed for XAF, but I can make my own [Delegate's DCNugetPackageBuilder](http://blog.delegate.at/2016/02/26/nuget-packages-devexpress-components.html)

**Using DXNugetPackageBuilder to make Nuget packages**

As per the instructions I downloaded the .pdb files extracted them to c:\tmp\symbols

I also downloaded DXNugetPackageBuilder and edited buildPackages.bat according to instructions.

Next I ran build.ps1 in elevated Powershell

This created the .nupkg files at C:\tmp\Nuget

By default this uses the files located at

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 18.1\Components\Bin\Framework
```

and the .pdb files located at

```
c:\tmp\symbols
```

**Using Nuget.Exe and the Credential Provider to push the packages to the feed**

The Connect To Feed screen mentions I need to download Nuget.exe and the credential provider
[image: download credential provider]

Here are the docs on [the Credentials Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/extensibility/nuget-exe-credential-providers)

I unzipped the VSTS CredentialProviders Nuget.Exe is included.

The next step is to follow the instructions given by the "add this feed" section of the Connect To Feed screen.

For example

```
nuget.exe push -Source "SBDDevExpress" -ApiKey VSTS c:\tmp\Nuget\DevExpress.Data.18.1.6.0.nupkg
```

I ran into an access denied issue [that got solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52798199/how-do-i-grant-access-to-nugetcredentialprovider-to-push-my-package-into-my-azur)

then I was able to push all the packages I wanted.

**Set the Nuget Package Source**

In VS2017 with my solution open I used  Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings

I added package settings with the Azure endpoint set up as a package source.

**Errors building**

When I run the build pipeline I get errors like

```
The type or namespace DevExpress could not be found are you missing a directive or assembly reference?
```

[image: looking at the pipeline error]

From studying Updater.cs and Module.cs
It seems I am missing the following namespaces from the Nuget feed.

```
DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC;
DevExpress.ExpressApp.Updating;
DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.PermissionPolicy;
```

**[Update]**

DevExpress suggested I compare the dlls generated in the bin folder with my package feed.

I found several missing files and pushed their packages.

I now have

```
XafMobile.Module\Properties\licenses.licx(1.0): Error LC0003: Unable to resolve type 'DevExpress.ExpressApp.ModuleBase"
```

[image: showing in the build output]

I can see from the source code that ModuleBase is a public class in DevExpress.ExpressApp

I am wondering if this is something to do with reflection.

There is some mention of it at Dev Express [support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T490157/the-unable-to-resolve-type-defined-in-licenses-licx-error-appears)

[Update]

I tried removing the licence files and syncing the project.
Now the errors show as missing assembly references

[image: missing assembly references]

Also When I rebuild my solution the license files are missing from the properties folders

I wonder if [this helps explain it](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q525711/licenses-licx-file-not-generated)

[Update]

Manuel Grunder [DevExpress MVP] and DXNugetPackageBuilder author explained that

"
When working with nuget.packages you need to reference them via nuget as well
[as he explains here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T681650/missing-name-spaces-from-self-made-nuget-packages)
"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183773/enable-ssl-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is [explained here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T681650/missing-name-spaces-from-self-made-nuget-packages)

"When working with nuget.packages you need to reference them via nuget as well. Thats the reason why it did not work in the first place."

Comment: Now DevExpress have Nuget support for XAF there is no need to set up an artifact in Azure.to store the packages.