# How do I set up an XAF Mobile solution to use SSL on localhost?

Tags: ssl, xaf

When I open the properties page of my Xaf Mobile Solution I can see that the project url is

```
http://localhost:2065/
```

I want to use SSL in my development environment.

What do I need to do?

[image: project url]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 kinds of project properties.
Those accessed by right clicking the project and those accessed by pressing F4

Highlight the Mobile Project and Press F4
Then you can see the SSL Enabled property with the URL
[image: Press F4]

Copy the URL and paste it into the Project Url on the web tab of the properties

[image: Right Click Project]

Then you may be up to the next issue

[The resource cannot be found](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T607611/the-the-resource-cannot-be-found-error-occurs-when-a-mobile-application-is-published-on)

Copying from [Dev Express Help](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T571854/xaf-mobile-metadataservices-svc-theme-not-found-in-ssl-url)

**Next step will be to replace MainDemo with my solution name**

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="msgSize" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
    </binding>
    <binding name="msgSizeSSL" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MainDemo.Mobile.DataService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="msgSize" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler"/>
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="msgSizeSSL" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler"/>
  </service>
  <service name="MainDemo.Mobile.MetadataService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="msgSize" contract="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Mobile.Services.IMobileMetadataService"/>
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="msgSizeSSL" contract="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Mobile.Services.IMobileMetadataService"/>
  </service>
  <service name="MainDemo.Mobile.DownloadReportService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="msgSize" contract="DevExpress.ExpressApp.ReportsV2.Mobile.IXafDownloadReportService" />
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="msgSizeSSL" contract="DevExpress.ExpressApp.ReportsV2.Mobile.IXafDownloadReportService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183773/enable-ssl-in-visual-studio