# Using Fiddler and web REST API

Tags: c#, rest, fiddler

Previously I wrote a web REST API using C# with Visual Studio 2019.  It was connecting via HTTP and not HTTPS.  To debug it, I used Fiddler with the composer and sent a POST to the API and then looked at the response.  I am now trying to do the same thing except it is an HTTPS request.  Since I have successfully done this with HTTP, I am 99% sure I have everything correct (URL, request body, API, etc.).  The problem is that I immediately receive an error.

*502 - [Fiddler] The connection to 'localhost' failed. 
System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection with server.fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to localhost (for #63) failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. < An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.*

I am pretty sure this has something to do with some type of certificate but my knowledge of HTTPS and certificates is VERY limited.  I understand the concept but very little more.  Can some one point me in the right direction for getting the config correct so the two can talk?  If I have right keywords, I can go digging but I don't know what is wrong so I don't know what to search for.

Comment: Have you enabled https in your project properties?

Comment: I've run into the same issue as well.  Try testing with Posman or the VSCode Rest Client: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client

Comment: How do you enable https in the project properties?  I don't see anything related to https.

Answer (score 0):

I just found part of my answer on this page - [Enable SSL in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183773/enable-ssl-in-visual-studio).  I will say that I'm not 100% sure this is all that was needed.  I've fought with this for a while so I might have done some other needed certificate stuff along the way and not realized it was also needed.  Someday I will start with a fresh Windows install and do just the instructions in the link and will this update this with the results.

I have also learned that, generally speaking, there is really no difference between an HTTP and an HTTPS REST API program from a development point of view.  Using the info in the above link, I took an exiting project that I had written for HTTP and flipped the SSL and change the web address (all included in the link) and it ran with an HTTPS connection.

Now if I can only figure out how to change the SSL URL to what I want so I can remember it.