# CORS not enabled although configured for web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Trying to access a local API made in web API 2.0 (asp.net) from an angular project.

The request results in

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:50581/MD/GetUserMD' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

But I don't understand as I added EnableCors to the webAPIConfig

[image]

and specified these in all the controllers.
[image]

Is there something I could try to resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS allows you to specify who is able to call your API. So more is needed than just enabling CORS; you need to set the policies. There are a couple ways to do that:

1. With the `[EnableCors]` attribute, which can be set at either the Controller or Action level:

```cs
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

2. For your entire application:

```cs
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
}
```

You *can* set the origin to `"*"` to allow any website to make requests to your API, but be careful with that.

More information here: [Enable cross-origin requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#scope-rules-for-enablecors)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Gabriel! I found out that Chrome blocks localhost API calls for security reasons and so I have been developing with web security disabled. Do you know a way to resolve this?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534759/chrome-cors-error-on-request-to-localhost-dev-server-from-remote-site), Chrome will block it unless 1. The main site is HTTPS and 2. The API has appropriate CORS headers. So with my answer you can satisfy #2. To satisfy #1, you need to enable HTTPS on your `localhost:50581` site. If that is a development site in Visual Studio, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41341491/1202807).

Comment: I'll make sure to try, thank you for your answer!