# IIS express "This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response"

Tags: ssl, iis-express

I'm running a `Skoruba IdentityServer4` project `https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin

`Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.2.2`

The project was working fine, but after disabling/enabling SSL im getting  `This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response` in chrome

When running `Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin`

Note: in Firefox I get `An error occurred during a connection to localhost:44303. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.`

I checked all my certificate definition according to: [Enable SSL in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183773/enable-ssl-in-visual-studio) and it seems OK

But since the menus in this version of Visual Studio have completely changed I couldn't follow any of the instruction I found on the WEB

EDIT:
I found in [https://serverfault.com/questions/379772/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-ssl-received-a-record-that-exceeded-the-maximum-perm:`That](https://serverfault.com/questions/379772/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-ssl-received-a-record-that-exceeded-the-maximum-perm:%60That) usually means that you are sending a HTTPS request to a HTTP service`

So I tried to search & replace the port from `44303` to `44304` and the ssl is working but I get a new error:

[image]

`Sorry, there was an error : invalid_request Invalid redirect_uri`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct definitions that solves the problem for me:

```js
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44301",
      "sslPort": 44304
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44301;https://localhost:44304"
    }
  }
}
```

The strange thing is that on one of my working station the port 44303 is working, and on the other it is gone for good, even after reset I get `The connection to localhost was interrupted. Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

So I just had to change the port to 44304

But then I got the `Invalid redirect_uri`

I found that on one of my working station the VS generate a log under each project `Log` folder and there I saw:

2022-05-28 10:28:33.864 +03:00 [ERR] Invalid redirect_uri: http://localhost/api/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html

{"ClientId":"skoruba_identity_admin_api_swaggerui",
"ClientName":"skoruba_identity_admin_api_swaggerui",
"RedirectUri":null,
"AllowedRedirectUris":["https://localhost/api/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html"],

Notice that the url doesn't start with `https`
This can be solved directly in the DB:

[image]

Or in the Admin: Clients > skoruba_identity_admin_api_swaggerui > Basic

`Save Client` at the buttom

[image]