# JQuery Datatables taking time to load on Internet Explorer but loading fine on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, datatables

My datatable code is:

```
(function (){
var table = $('#previousExceptionTable').DataTable({
dom: 'lrtip',
initComplete: function () {
   alert("initComplete");//an alert box just to check control location
       this.api().columns([1]).every( function () {
        var column = this;
...
});
```

When I am using chrome browser I am getting the alert box and result quickly (withing 1-2) seconds but when I am using IE it takes almost 4-5 minutes to get the result and alert box.

I get this error on IE

```
 localhost is not responding due to a long-running script
```

but after waiting for 4-5 minutes I get the result.

Earlier I was using CDN for datatable so I thought of downloading the JS file and then using it to enhance speed but it was of no use.
I tried to reset IE settings it didnt work
 Do you guys have any idea about descreasing the loading time on IE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [localhost doesn't open in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764008/localhost-doesnt-open-in-ie9)

Comment: can you specify which IE version you are using?? You can also check this link also https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/34425/datatables-is-not-working-on-ie-11

Comment: @StephanT. , it is not duplicate , sorry

Comment: @Atanu, I am using IE 11 but forcing my JSP to load in IE 10

Comment: @Atanu, I tried forcing the page to load in edge but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with IE (10/11/edge) but not with a .Datatable().

This worked for me, (add to the 'head' element in the HTML)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
```

Comment: @Ayush if you could send a jsfiddle with the code, i could take a closer look for you :)

Comment: please tell me what exact piece of code you want as adding a fiddle would be quite difficult as I am using many tiles for the JSP page. Do you want to see the JSP Head tag or the Datatable function code?

Comment: @Ayush Well if i can't see the whole code, i cannot identify if IE is the whole problem. There is always a chance that IE + another thing is causing the preformance issue